# PHP - strstr() returns false but the $haystack contains the $needle

Tags: php, html, string, url, strstr

This is a very strange error, i am trying to fix it without success.
I am trying to check if a link contains a string:

```
$actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
echo $actual_link;
```

The output is:

```
http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/plesk-site-preview/***********.com/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/
```

Then:

```
if(strstr($actual_link,"plesk-site-preview")  ){
echo"<meta name='robots' content='noindex'>";
}
```

The problem is that strstr return false despite the substring `plesk-site-preview` is contained in `http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/plesk-site-preview/***********.com/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/`.

How can i fix this error?

**EDIT:**

I have inserted before `if(strstr($actual_link,"plesk-site-preview")  ){` the following line for testing purpose:

```
$actual_link='http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/plesk-site-preview/***********.com/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/';
```

Now the code is working! It seems that the string assigned at the variable $actual_link is lost before the IF statement.

Comment: Try `if(strstr($actual_link,"plesk-site-preview") !== FALSE ){`

Comment: @NineBerry i have inserted your code but the error remains! Please note that my code is exact and there are not further lines of code between `echo $actual_link;` and the `IF` statement.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this question>?

Comment: @Mawg, No i can't fix this error.

Comment: Did you try checking the result with `!== False` ? That should work

Answer (score 1):

The [documentaion](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) says

> string strstr ( string $haystack , mixed $needle [, bool $before_needle = FALSE ] )
>
> Returns part of haystack string starting from and including the first
> occurrence of needle to the end of haystack.
>
> Returns the portion of string, or FALSE if needle is not found.

And you code

```
if(strstr($actual_link,"plesk-site-preview"))
```

Perhaps it ought to be

```
if(strstr($actual_link,"plesk-site-preview") != "")
```

as it returns a string, not a boolean if successful.

Hmm, actually it would be better to

```
 if(strstr($actual_link,"plesk-site-preview") !== FALSE)
```

Comment: To use strict type checking, use `!==`

Comment: @Mawg I have replaced my code with `if(strstr($actual_link,"plesk-site-preview" != FALSE) )` but the error has not been fixed! Please note also that you have forgotten a `)` in your code.

Comment: @NineBerry is correct, `!=` ought to be `!==`. The point here is that many PHP functions return FLASE for failure and the proper way to test is `!== FALSE`; it's a common pattern

Comment: Of course, if you used a debugger, you wouldn't have to ask us this :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you need check string presence of a substring in a string then you can use [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php), for example:

```
if(strpos($actual_link, "plesk-site-preview")){
    echo"<meta name='robots' content='noindex'>";
}
```

This way is better, because strpos is faster than strstr

Comment: I have tried with your  code but the error has not been fixed!

Comment: @Daniele, This condition is correct. You can check it, for example:

    `if(strpos($actual_link, "plesk-site-preview")){
        echo "Substing finded";
    }`

You should check other code.

Comment: @Daniele, I was tested it. My code: `$actual_link = "http://84.200.70.56/plesk-site-preview/***********.com/84.200.70.56/";
if(strpos($actual_link,"plesk-site-preview")  ){
    echo "Substring found";
}` and it works

Comment: Try print $actual_link variable before if statement

Comment: `strpos($actual_link, "plesk-site-preview") !== FALSE` will solve your problem